# Showing an Integral Exists

Tags: integration

How do I show that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$ exists?

I have tried bounding it by $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx$, but this does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Bound it by $\frac1{1+x^2}$. Notice that 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ exists and equal $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: After subbing in $x=$tan$\theta$, when changing the limits, there are many of values of $\theta$ st tan$\theta=0,\infty$. How do I know which values of $\theta$ to pick?

Comment: Abel-Dirichlet Test?

Comment: @usainlightning $\arctan$ only uses $(-\pi/2\ \, .. \, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Split it into

$$\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} dx = \int_0^{1} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} dx + \int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} dx \leq $$
$$\leq \int_0^{1} \ 1\ dx + \int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = 1+1=2$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Why don't we put $x=\tan\theta$ to find $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\cdots=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2}\sin^2\theta\ d\theta$$

$$=\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2}\frac{1-\cos2\theta}2\ d\theta$$

**See also**:  [Trigonometric substitutions](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html)